# Rails 3 - Image src is not loading for localhost url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, email

In rails 3.2.13, I am trying to display an image in email template. When I used cloudfront url(env: production and test) then images will load, If I used `http://localhost:3000` url then image will not load.

In development.rb, I have added a line as shown below

```
ENV["HOST"] = "localhost:3000"
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => ENV["HOST"]}
config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"
```

If I tried to print an image path separately then exact path`(Eg: http://localhost:3000/avatars/1/tiny/avatar_20141229075627.png)` will display but in `src` it is blank `src="about:blank"`

How can I display localhost images in email template(gmail/yopmail)?

[image]

Comment: Show me your email template where you are displaying image path!!!

Comment: Image has been added. First, I am trying to print only the path then `<img>`

Comment: comment line # config.action_controller.asset_host and menation as root_url instead of root_path in your template...

Comment: In template, I am using html <img> tag to display an image.
`Eg: <img src="<%= http://localhost:3000/avatars/1/tiny/avatar_20141229075627.png %>" />`
Even this static image will not load.

Comment: I guess you are working with Production mode have to see asset pipeline for Rails....!!!

Comment: No. I am working in development mode and through console I am sending an email for testing.

Answer (score 2):

It's is not possible to display local host image in email template. You have to take services like amazone to store your image in the server and display in email template.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are sending mails on gmail/yopmail from development environment. if this is the case, you need to use service like cloudfront to upload the image. so image can be accessed globally from anywhere.

Images of localhost are accessible only on your local.